# How reset index count to 1 when looping through a UIImageView

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a UIImageView that displays picture cards of the Alphabet, A-Z.  I use a segment control to determine if the cards display in order A-Z or are randomly displayed.

Whenever I start the in order, if I switch over to random and then back to in order, the index starts at where I left off.  So if I was at card C, switch to random, do a few and then switch back to in order, the next card is D, I want it to start over at A (index 1).
 How would I reset the index counter to index 1?

I'm using the below variable:
`var number = 1`

I called that on my button click:

```
@IBAction func dealBTN(_ sender: Any) {
        if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card1")
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(number)")
            number = number % 26 + 1
        }
        else if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            let Number = Int.random(in: 1...26)
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(Number)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a property called `number` to keep track of your next card to display when they are in order.  Simply set it to `1` whenever you are picking a *random* card so that the index is back at `1` the next time you choose an *ordered* card:

```
if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(number)")
    number = number % 26 + 1
}
else if segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
    let random = Int.random(in: 1...26)
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(random)")
    number = 1
}
```